# Print slowly in terminal PYTHON

Tags: python, performance, printing, terminal, line

I was wondering if you could help me print slowly in Python. We're tasked with writing a game for this course and I've done a very basic small intro but I want the text to print slower and I have no clue how to target single lines see code below. I'd like the print functions to print slower on some parts but when I code further I want some paragraphs that will be written later to print faster. Can anyone give me a dumbed-down version to help an absolute beginner (I started 4 days ago with coding) Thanks in Advance!

```
Escape_the_python = "Welcome to Escape the Python! What is your name?..."

 print (Escape_the_python)
 name = input("")
while True:
 print (f"Welcome {name}. Are you ready to begin?")
 begin = input ("")
 if begin.lower() == ("yes".lower)():
     print ("Let the game begin...")
     break
 elif begin.lower() == ("no".lower)():
     print ("Type Yes when you're ready!")
 else:
     print ("Invalid option please try again.")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what You are looking for (btw did this for the first time, never even thought about this):

```
import time

sentence = 'hello world'

for char in sentence:
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(char, end='')
```

`0.5` represents seconds

Answer (score 0):

I usually make it like this. Easy and customizable

```
import time
import sys

def slowPrint(string, speed=0.05):
    for char in string:
        sys.stdout.write(char)
        sys.stdout.flush()
        time.sleep(speed)

slowPrint('Hello World!', 0.1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).